# ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, iptables

Everything was working perfectly fine. Did some `git push`es with no problems.

Today I decided to update my framework to the latest version, so it changed the directory structure of my project a bit. So within Bitbucket, I created a new repository (`dev1.project.com`) and renamed my project's folder from `OldName` to `dev1.project.com`.

I edited `.git/config` to point my new repository:

```ini
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://bitbucket.org/user/dev1.project.com.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

When I do  `git remote -v`, I get :

```
origin  ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/dev1.project.com.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/dev1.project.com.git (push)
```

I go back to my project folder, and type:

```bash
git init
git add .      
git commit -m 'my first commit'
git push -u origin master
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The command `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` gets me the same messages as above.

The command: `git config --get remote.origin.url`    shows:

```
git@bitbucket.org:user/dev1.project.com.git
```

[status.bitbucket.org](https://status.bitbucket.org/) shows that everything works fine on their side.

Not sure why it was working before, and not working now.

I'm on CentOS and i'm not sure what I should do next. I've seen a couple `iptables`-related answers, so I tried this:

```
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

service iptables stop
service ip6tables stop
service sshd reload
service iptables start
service ip6tables start
```

But still nothing, any ideas?

Ps: I've also updated CentOS from 6.6 to 6.7 and PHP 5.4 to 5.6, but didn't think it would matter.

#### Update #1

Ran the following commands:

```bash
ps x | grep ssh-agent
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add     # then it asked for my password
```

Got the message:

```
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Then

```bash
service sshd restart
```

But still nothing

#### Update #2

I email my VPS hosting company, asking if there is anything I can do to open port 22, and they answered:

> I have disabled the monitoring system on the host node blocking traffic to Bitbucket.

I don't know what it means, but everything was working after that, and apparently I couldn't do anything about it.

Comment: There is a typo: `service sshd restart` should be `service ssh restart`

Comment: could you also include links to where you found these solutions?

Comment: Up, I the same with this error. But I don't know how to fix them, can you explain about solution?

Comment: This was very useful, I am running RHEL 7 on a VM and after your post I temporarily disabled the firewall on my router and I was able to establish a connection. Thank you for posting the solution to your issue.

Comment: See also my Q: [Cannot `git clone` Bitbucket repo on Windows: `ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76918674/4561887) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925306/4561887).

Answer (score 141):

I have done below mentioned things and it started working.

```
 vim ~/.ssh/config
```

Add these lines and save it.

```
Host bitbucket.org
    Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
    Port  443
```

For Windows:

- Go to the place where your **.ssh** folder is located (`run %USERPROFILE%`).
- open the **.ssh** folder and create a file with the name **config** without any extension.
- Paste the below content and save it.

  ```
  Host github.com
            Hostname ssh.github.com
            Port 443

  Host bitbucket.org
            Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
            Port  443
  ```

Comment: Many thanks! Could you elaborate what is the problem here?

Comment: what does altssh do here ?

Comment: Please check following links. it will help you to understand the problem

https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/

http://www.garbers.co.za/2014/03/03/connecting-to-bitbucket-on-https-port/

Comment: didn't work! says: ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: how do I save the changes on MacOS?

Comment: I ended up discovering the same thing: [The fix: route SSH traffic to Bitbucket.org through port 443 instead...if your network admins are blocking external traffic on port 22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925306/4561887). I go into a lot more detail, and explain how to use `nmap` and `ncat` to identify if your network admins are blocking traffic to bitbucket on port 22.

Comment: this work perfectly! thanks. @amm965 the command it's using `vim` so in order to save the changes do:  Press `Esc` then press ` :`  then press `w` and finally  `Enter` . Not all at the same time, just one by one. You don't need to use  `vim`, you could also use `nano`: `nano ~/.ssh/config` . To save `nano` simply press `Ctrl + O` then `Enter`

Comment: Even in 2023 this works and this was not listed as a step on their website explaining how to setup things for ssh key based access

Answer (score 2):

try to use this command.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

"id_rsa" is the file you create when you generate ssh key.